# Spark dataframes: Extract a column based on the value of another column

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe with transactions with a joined price list:

```
+----------+----------+------+-------+-------+
|   paid   | currency | EUR  |  USD  |  GBP  |
+----------+----------+------+-------+-------+
|   49.5   |   EUR    | 99   |  79   |  69   |
+----------+----------+------+-------+-------+
```

A customer has paid 49.5 in EUR, as shown in the "currency" column. I now want to compare that paid price with the price from the price list.

Therefor I need to access the correct column based on the value of "currency" like so:

```
df.withColumn("saved", df.col(df.col($"currency")) - df.col("paid"))
```

which I hoped would become

```
df.withColumn("saved", df.col("EUR") - df.col("paid"))
```

This fails, however. I tried all things I could image, including and UDF, getting nowhere.

I guess there is some elegant solution for this? Can somebody help out here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assuming that the column names match values in the `currency` column:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{lit, col, coalesce}
import org.apache.spark.sql.Column 

// Dummy data
val df = sc.parallelize(Seq(
  (49.5, "EUR", 99, 79, 69), (100.0, "GBP", 80, 120, 50)
)).toDF("paid", "currency", "EUR", "USD", "GBP")

// A list of available currencies 
val currencies: List[String] = List("EUR", "USD", "GBP")

// Select listed value
val listedPrice: Column = coalesce(
  currencies.map(c => when($"currency" === c, col(c)).otherwise(lit(null))): _*)

df.select($"*", (listedPrice - $"paid").alias("difference")).show

// +-----+--------+---+---+---+----------+
// | paid|currency|EUR|USD|GBP|difference|
// +-----+--------+---+---+---+----------+
// | 49.5|     EUR| 99| 79| 69|      49.5|
// |100.0|     GBP| 80|120| 50|     -50.0|
// +-----+--------+---+---+---+----------+
```

with SQL equivalent of `listedPrice` expression being something like this:

```sql
COALESCE(
  CASE WHEN (currency = 'EUR') THEN EUR ELSE null,
  CASE WHEN (currency = 'USD') THEN USD ELSE null,
  CASE WHEN (currency = 'GBP') THEN GBP ELSE null
)
```

Alternative using `foldLeft`:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.when

val listedPriceViaFold = currencies.foldLeft(
  lit(null))((acc, c) => when($"currency" === c, col(c)).otherwise(acc))

df.select($"*", (listedPriceViaFold - $"paid").alias("difference")).show

// +-----+--------+---+---+---+----------+
// | paid|currency|EUR|USD|GBP|difference|
// +-----+--------+---+---+---+----------+
// | 49.5|     EUR| 99| 79| 69|      49.5|
// |100.0|     GBP| 80|120| 50|     -50.0|
// +-----+--------+---+---+---+----------+
```

where `listedPriceViaFold` translates to following SQL:

```sql
CASE
  WHEN (currency = 'GBP') THEN GBP
  ELSE CASE
    WHEN (currency = 'USD') THEN USD
    ELSE CASE
      WHEN (currency = 'EUR') THEN EUR
      ELSE null
```

Unfortunately I am not aware of any built-in functions which could express directly SQL like this

```sql
CASE currency
    WHEN 'EUR' THEN EUR
    WHEN 'USD' THEN USD
    WHEN 'GBP' THEN GBP
    ELSE null
END
```

but you can use this construct in raw SQL.

It my assumption is not true you can simply add mapping between column name and a value in the `currency` column.

**Edit**:

Another option, which could be efficient if source supports predicate pushdown and efficient column pruning, is to subset by currency and union:

```
currencies.map(
  // for each currency filter and add difference
  c => df.where($"currency" === c).withColumn("difference", $"paid" - col(c))
).reduce((df1, df2) => df1.unionAll(df2)) // Union
```

It is equivalent to SQL like this:

```sql
SELECT *,  EUR - paid AS difference FROM df WHERE currency = 'EUR'
UNION ALL
SELECT *,  USD - paid AS difference FROM df WHERE currency = 'USD'
UNION ALL
SELECT *,  GBP - paid AS difference FROM df WHERE currency = 'GBP'
```

Comment: Your answer introduced a [different](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33707191/dataframe-state-before-save-and-after-load-whats-different) problem ;)

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of a way doing this with `DataFrame`s, and I doubt that there is simple way, but if you take that table into an `RDD`:

```
// On top of my head, warn if wrong.
// Would be more elegant with match .. case 
def d(l: (Int, String, Int, Int, Int)): Int = {
  if(l._2 == "EUR")
    l._3 - l._1
  else if (l._2 == "USD")
    l._4 - l._1
  else 
    l._5 -l._1
}
val rdd = df.rdd
val diff = rdd.map(r => (r, r(d)))
```

Will most likely raise type errors, I hope you can navigate around those.

Comment: Thanks! There's a couple of more currencies so I wanted to avoid if/else's or nested when().otherwise() constructs.

Comment: Speaking of which, my problem seems to be I cannot get the literal value of that column $"currency" and I was wondering how when($"column", [then]) works. I was wondering whether the part of the code [there](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Column.scala) would help me?! `lit(condition).expr`