# Dataframe state before save and after load - what's different?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, rdd, parquet

I have a DF that contains some SQL expressions (coalesce, case/when etc.).
I later try to map/flatMap this DF where I get an `Task not serializable` error, due to the fields that contain the SQL expressions.

(Why I need to map/flatMap this DF is a separate question)

When I save this DF to a Parquet file and load it afterwards, the error is gone and I can convert to RDD and do transformations no problem!

How is the DF different before saving and after loading? In some way, the SQL expressions must have been evaluated and made persistent. How can I achieve the same thing **without** saving/loading? (df.perists() did not do the trick `;(`)

Here's test code:

```
val data = Seq( (1, "sku1", "EUR", 99.0, 89.0), (2, "sku2", "USD", 89.0, 79.0),  (3, "sku3", "USD", 49.0, 39.9) )
val aditionalStuffForCertainSKUsMap = Map("sku1" -> List(10, 20, 30))

val listedPrice = coalesce(
    List("EUR", "USD").map(c => when($"currency" === c, col(c)).otherwise(lit(null))): _*)

val df = (sc.parallelize(data)
    .toDF("id", "sku", "currency", "EUR", "USD")
    .withColumn("price_in_given_currency",  when($"currency" === "EUR", $"EUR"*2).otherwise(1))
 //   .withColumn("fails_price_in_given_currency", listedPrice)
)
df.show
df.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).parquet("test_df")
```

The data contains a `sku` and some SKUs represent bundles, like sku1, for which I want to add some other fields to the DF. **Only when I try to access this Map[String, List[Int]]** within the map() I get complaints with the `fails_price_in_given_currency` column, not so with the `price_in_given_currency`:

```
// If I load the df first, the map() works even when using `fails_price_in_given_currency`
//val df = sqlContext.read.parquet("test_df") 

val out = df.map(d => {
  val key = d.getAs[String]("sku")
  aditionalStuffForCertainSKUsMap.getOrElse(key, None)
})
```

The error is thrown when I use `fails_price_in_given_currency` instead. If I however load `df` before the map, it will run again!

Comment: Could you provide more details? Reproducible example would be great. Generally speaking there should be no difference whatsoever. If I had to guess you're using `spark-shell` and something goes wrong with closure serialization. It seems to be a common issue in 1.5.

Comment: I am using 1.5.1, but using Zeppelin (which might be using shell under the hood?).  I am trying to put some test code together (which probably then works ;) )

Comment: I've been thinking about an interactive session in general.

Comment: To be precise, the error is `Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.spark.sql.Column
Serialization stack:
 - object not serializable (class: org.apache.spark.sql.Column, value: coalesce(CASE WHEN (order_currency_code = AUD) THEN AUD ELSE null,CASE WHEN (order_currency_code = GBP) THEN GBP ELSE null,CASE WHEN (order_currency_code = JPY) THEN JPY ELSE null,CASE WHEN (order_currency_code = USD) THEN USD ELSE null,CASE WHEN (order_currency_code = EUR) THEN EUR ELSE null))`

Comment: So the short answer is there is no difference whatsoever. The problem is in your "workspace".  I'll try to provide a little bit longer answer later if I don't  forget but generally speaking the best advice I can give you is to keep things tidy.

Comment: I am facing the same problem here, I would appreciate you someone can post the solution. thanks

Comment: @Rami feel free to upvote the question!