# Pyspark dataframes: Extract a column based on the value of another column

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a dataframe with the following columns and corresponding values (forgive my formatting but dont know how to put it in table format):

```
Src_ip     dst_ip     V1     V2     V3     top
"A"         "B"       xx     yy     zz     "V1"
```

Now I want to add a column, lets say `top_value` which takes the value of column corresponding to the string in V1.

```
Src_ip     dst_ip     V1     V2     V3     top   top_value
"A"         "B"       xx     yy     zz     "V1"     xx
```

So basically, get the value corresponding to the value in the column "top" and make a new column named "top_value"

I have tried by creating UDFs as well as using the string as an alias but unable to do so. Can anyone please help.

Comment: See if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33638325/spark-dataframes-extract-a-column-based-on-the-value-of-another-column

Comment: Hi Shaido, Thank you for the editing and help.

Comment: No problems, if the link didn't help you solve it maybe you can add some more input and what the expected output should be. Then the question would be a bit clearer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can collect the `V1`, `V2` and `V3` columns as `struct` and pass to a `udf` function with the `top` column and extract the value as

## scala

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
def findValueUdf = udf((strct: Row, top: String) => strct.getAs[String](top))

df.withColumn("top_value", findValueUdf(struct("V1", "V2", "V3"), col("top")))
```

which should give you

```
+------+------+---+---+---+---+---------+
|Src_ip|dst_ip|V1 |V2 |V3 |top|top_value|
+------+------+---+---+---+---+---------+
|A     |B     |xx |yy |zz |V1 |xx       |
+------+------+---+---+---+---+---------+
```

## pyspark

equivalent code in pyspark would be

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as f
from pyspark.sql import types as t
def findValueUdf(strct, top):
    return strct[top]

FVUdf = f.udf(findValueUdf, t.StringType())

df.withColumn("top_value", FVUdf(f.struct("V1", "V2", "V3"), f.col("top")))
```

Moreover you can define the column names in a list to be used in `struct` function so that you don't have to hard code them.

I hope the answer is helpful

Comment: Even today don't we have an out of box function to achieve this?